# Rails test database values do not match fixture values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, fixtures

This seems like a very strange problem to me. I have a table which contained a boolean value field. I changed that field to be a string since I now want more possible values than just yes or no. I ran the migration and reran the tests. The database table structures show that the field type has been changed to a varchar(255). But every time I run the test, the database field values are still showing 'f' or 't'. But in my fixture file, I am now setting the values to "No" or "Yes":

```
one:
  value: No

two:
  value: Yes
```

I've tried purging the database and rerunning the test. But nothing helps. I have no idea where boolean values are coming from since I changed the type. I can't think of anything else that needs to be cleared out. I'm sure there is something simple I'm forgetting to do but I don't see it. If more information is needed to answer this, please let me know.

I'm running rails 4.1.5 with ruby 2.1.4. I'm running the tests using SQLite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values Yes and No are interpreted as booleans in Yaml files.  Try changing it to:

```
one:
  value: "No"

two:
  value: "Yes"
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks! I should have done my Google search on Yaml instead of fixtures and database types.